# id changed while importing wizard with Navicat

Tags: database-migration, navicat

I exported a wizard from PostgreSQL and then imported it to MySQL, but the column `id` changed which crashed the relation among the tables in the database. `id` is a primary key in my app, and I thought that might be the problem. Is there any method to fix this and keep the `id` during the migration. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by dumping the SQL and Data file instead of exporting a wizard. After executing the queries, the database looks good.